# Let $G$ be a group with $K\unlhd G$ and Abelian $N\unlhd G$. Is $G/(NK)$ an Abelian group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

Let $G$ be a group such that $N$ is an Abelian normal subgroup of $G$ and $K$ is just a normal subgroup of $G$, is $G/(NK)$ an Abelian group? Also we know that $NK$ is normal in $G$.

I am not really sure how to show it, assuming it's correct which I don't know for sure.
Writing down: $g(NK)h(NK)=g(NK)g^{-1}ghg^{-1}g(NK)g^{-1}$, and I know that also $NK$ is normal in $G$ the last equality means $g(NK)g^{-1}=NK$, but I want to show that: $g(NK)h(NK)=h(NK)g(NK)$.

Confused, how do you suggest me to get unstuck?
Thanks!

Comment: No, $N$ abelian does not imply $G/N$ abelian. Did you want to assume that $G/N$ is abelian? Then $G/NK$ will be as well (as factor of an abelian group).

Comment: For a counterexample, you can assume that $K$ is the trivial subgroup.

Comment: Yes, @ahulpke for a different exercise I have both $N$ and $G/N$ Abelian. Thanks!